# How can I use a loop to import files to pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have several .txt files that I need to import to work in pandas, given a specific condition. Right now I do the same procedure for each one. I want to do it using a for-loop.This is what I have tried:

Each key is asociated with a different .txt file

All files are in same folder

```
filenames = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

for i in filenames:
    if name == i:
        location = r'C:\Users\Folder\ + 'i'.txt'
```

What is the correct syntax to write that location path so that it can be used in a loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to concatenate the strings this way:

```
location = 'C:\\Users\\Folder\\' + i + '.txt'
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
'C:\Users\Folder\\' + str(i) + '.txt'
```

or

```
'C:\Users\Folder\%s.txt' % i
```

or

```
'C:\Users\Folder\%s.txt'.format(i)
```